# Pseudo class or Pseudo Element

Tags: css, border, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

I have a `div` element with a class of `.parent-div`. It has a `border-bottom` that is `1px` thick and `608px` wide. The div itself is `600px` wide. I need to make the last 20% of the `border-bottom` a different height than the rest. I have tried using `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements, but they don't seem to be working. Can someone help me achieve this effect? Here's the CSS for the `.parent-div`:

```css
.parent-div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 608px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 100px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bdbdbd;
  padding-bottom: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-div"></div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'the div itself if 600px wide'? Are there two divs. Please shouw your HTML and also the attempt that you made with before or after pseudo element.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I fixed it. 

'<div class="centered-div">#todo</div>
    <div class="parent-div">
      <div class="child-div" id="all">All</div>
      <div class="child-div">Active</div>
      <div class="child-div">Completed</div>
    </div>

    <form id="form">
      <input type="text" name="detail" placeholder="add details" />

      <button>Add</button>
    </form>

    <div id="results"></div>}'

Comment: Do not post answers here in the comment section. Create an answer below